# network driver or wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-drivers

why does it not support all network adapter driver by default ? i have RTL8723DE .when i install ubuntu it does not show wifi on its own. Everytime i install this i have to install driver for the same adapter , i says not wifi driver installed.

Comment: It is not supported right after install because Linux kernel doesn't support this adapter. You can search this site on how to install a driver.

Answer (score 1):

Reputable Linux-friendly hardware manufacturers contribute their drivers to the Linux kernel. That equipment is automatically detected and usable. Try to purchase hardware from those manufacturers with good Linux-friendly reputations.

Some manufacturers do not contribute their drivers to the Linux kernel. That equipment does not work well (or at all) in Linux. Other shady manufacturers claim Linux compatibility *but require you to compile their drivers*. Avoid purchasing equipment from those manufacturers.

- Hold your hardware vendor responsible for compatibility. You are their customer. You paid them. Return or exchange hardware that does not work.
- Improve Ubuntu by contributing your time and effort. Ubuntu is free. You are a *participant*, not a customer.